# SSH suddenly asking for password

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh

Note: this is a duplicate of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257525/ssh-suddenly-asking-for-password), since ali786 suggested it would be better here.

### General problem

I have my computer (Mac OSX 10.9.4) and a remote server (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) which I ssh into as root. I used `ssh-keygen` to create an ssh key (with no passphrase), added the public key to the server's `.ssh/authorized_keys`, and all was good in the world. Then, earlier today, `ssh` started asking me for a password again.

### What might have caused it

I'm really not sure what caused this - these are my best guesses:

- I did have to remove some files from my home directory on the remote server when I accidentally copied a git repository there (I didn't commit or anything from there, just copied things over and then `rm`'d them). From what I can tell from my command history, there aren't ssh-relevant files that I removed, just .git, .gitignore, and various *.sw? files leftover from vim.
- I ran `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server to see the fingerprints of (I think) the keys in that file.

### Relevant logs

When I run `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/mykey_rsa root@serverip`, I get this:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myusername/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to {ip address} [{ip address}] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/mykey_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file .ssh/mykey_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
No credentials cache file found

debug1:  An invalid name was supplied
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 2 752 43 14 2

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 5 14

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 2 for mech 1 3 6 1 4 1 311 2 2 10

debug1:  An unsupported mechanism was requested
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 5 1 5 2 7

debug1:  Miscellaneous failure (see text)
unknown mech-code 0 for mech 1 3 6 1 5 2 5

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA {fingerprint}
debug1: Host '{ip address}' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/otherkey_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/mykey_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@serverip's password:
```

I find it kind of strange that it tried a different ssh key (otherkey_rsa) before the one I told it to use (mykey_rsa), but I don't know enough about ssh to parse this well.

Meanwhile, the remote server's `/var/log/auth.log` helpfully says

```
Aug 12 02:04:19 servername sshd[22147]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Aug 12 02:04:19 servername sshd[22147]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root
```

### Permissions

Local/on my computer:

```
~/                     drwxr-xr-x+ 105 myusername staff 3570 Aug 11 23:14
~/.ssh/                drwx------   13 myusername staff  442 Aug 11 23:14
~/.ssh/mykey_rsa.pub   -rw-r--r--    1 myusername staff  397 Aug  5 20:52
~/.ssh/mykey_rsa       -rw-------    1 myusername staff 1675 Aug  5 20:52
```

Remotely/on the server:

```
~/                     drwxr-xr-x    8        501 staff 4096 Aug 12 02:16
~/.ssh/                drwx------    2       root root  4096 Aug 12 01:49
~/.ssh/authorized_keys -rw-------    1       root root   794 Aug 12 01:44
```

Remotely in the `/etc/ssh/` directory:

```
/etc/ssh $ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug 12 11:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 96 root root   4096 Aug 12 01:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 242091 Apr 14 08:13 moduli
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1690 Apr 14 08:13 ssh_config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2528 Apr 17 15:43 sshd_config
-rw-------  1 root root    672 Aug  6 00:41 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    606 Aug  6 00:41 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------  1 root root    227 Aug  6 00:41 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    178 Aug  6 00:41 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------  1 root root   1679 Aug  6 00:41 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    398 Aug  6 00:41 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    338 Apr 17 11:48 ssh_import_id
```

So it looks like the reason that it couldn't load `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key` is that it doesn't exist. Should it? If so, how can I create it?

I'm really stumped on this and would really appreciate help! Thank you!

Comment: Am I reading it wrong or your /root folder has rx permissions for everybody? And if it's not root, if it's "remoteuser", it still has too many permissions, isn't it?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key`?

Comment: I updated the post to show the permissions in `/etc/ssh/` - it looks like I don't have a `ssh_host_ed25519_key`, though I'm not sure what to do to get one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auth.log` is telling you exactly what the problem is: `/root` is owned by a user other than remoteuser or root, but it's somehow essential to your login. Either remoteuser *is* root, or its .ssh files are symlinks to somewhere under `/root`.

Also, I notice your ls line showing that `~/` is owned by user 501. That'll trigger the same failure.

My guess at what changed is that your `sshd_config` now specifies `StrictModes`.

Comment: Yes, `sshd_config` does specify StrictModes, but I think that's what it was originally as well.

I just figured out - the reason that my home directory was owned by user 501 was that I `rsync`ed a bunch of files there (`rsync` appears to be user 501 by default). `chown root .` in my home directory fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing out what was staring me in the face!